# Create regular expression match exact word with space followed by string length 8

Tags: php, regex, string

I am very new to regular expressions , I want to check in a sentence that matches with exact given word followed by space and a alphanumeric string starts with number and length of that string should be 8.From the below expression i am getting 1 as result and matches PO. But I am not getting how to create the rule to match PO followed by space and starts a string with first letter numeric and length with 8 characters.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$header = 'Amazon.fr PO 2YCLN4EM';
$k = preg_match("/[PO]*/", $header);
echo $k;
```

Comment: for reference http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$header = 'Amazon.fr PO 2YCLN4EM';

if (preg_match('/PO\ \d\w{7}/', $header, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Note that the function only returns whether you have a match or not. The third parameter contains the matches.

Comment: `\w` will match digit and alphabets. So no need to put `\d\w`

Comment: Actually, you are right! I started with \dA-Z pattern then changed A-Z to \w. I edited the answer.

Comment: minor improvement: The OP  wants 'to match the exact given word followed by space ...', the exact given _word_ being `PO`. Thus to exclude  `PO`being the suffix of a word, add a start anchor/non-word-character match to the regex: `/(^|\W)PO\ \d\w{7}/`.

Comment: @collapsar This is probably what he wants, but i think it wasn't stated in "to match PO followed by space" :)

Comment: @BeS Yes, I took the spec from the first line of his post ... :)

Comment: @BeS Thanks , it worked perfectly.Why i got negative voting? I said i am very new to regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows

Use `\d` and [Limiting Repetation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for match exact 7 times. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xH8iF6/2)

```
/PO\s\d\w{7}/
```

Comment: nitpick: \s means any whitespace char, not necessarily space only.